# Is it good practice to modify the reason phrase of an HTTP response?

Tags: http

HTTP errors have standardized response strings associated to their numeric codes. E.g. 404 "Not Found" or 500 "Internal Server Error". From the RFC it is clear that these strings are not relevant for the recognition of the error (only the numeric code is), but fiddling with e.g. tornado it is clear that the reason is generated automatically from the error code, and the reason parameter in the HTTPError class is present (according to the docs) to use non-standard codes, meaning that you are generally not supposed to use it.

My question is: is it good practice to change the reason string to something more specific for the actual error e.g. "500 Unable to connect to backend database" or "500 Hard disk is on fire", or is this practice discouraged, the error should stay "500 Internal Server Error" and any additional information should be in the payload?

Comment: The question is who would be using this information. Typical clients won't do anything with the information, perhaps not even display the value to the user. If you have a custom client which you know uses this information in some way, it's more or less up to you what to do with it.

Comment: Suppose I am developing my own client. @deceze

Comment: Well, then it's just between you and your server, baby. Just you and your server… ;)

Answer (score 24):

### HTTP/1.1

According to the [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230), the current reference for message syntax and routing in HTTP/1.1, the reason phrase exists with the *sole purpose of providing a textual description associated with the numeric status code* and a *client should ignore the reason phrase content*. The RFC also states that the *reason phrase can be empty*.

See the quote below:

> [**3.1.2. Status Line**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.2)
>
> The first line of a response message is the status-line, consisting
> of the protocol version, a space (`SP`), the status code, another
> space, a possibly empty textual phrase describing the status code,
> and ending with `CRLF`.
>
> ```
> status-line = HTTP-version SP status-code SP reason-phrase CRLF
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The reason-phrase element exists for the sole purpose of providing a
> textual description associated with the numeric status code, mostly
> out of deference to earlier Internet application protocols that were
> more frequently used with interactive text clients.  A client SHOULD
> ignore the reason-phrase content.
>
> ```
> reason-phrase = *( HTAB / SP / VCHAR / obs-text )
> ```

Quoting the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), the current reference for semantics and content of the HTTP/1.1 protocol:

> [**6.1. Overview of Status Codes**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.1)
>
> [...] The reason phrases listed here are only recommendations    --
> they can be replaced by local equivalents without affecting the protocol. [...]

In theory, there's *nothing* that stops you from changing the reason phrase.

However, the [existing reason phrases](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-49) are really well known and widely adopted. Assuming the client should ignore the reason phrase, I would say it's not correct place to send the error message. Consider using the response payload for it.

### HTTP/2

HTTP/2 doesn't support reason phrases at all. See the following quote from the [RFC 7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540):

> [**8.1.2.4.  Response Pseudo-Header Fields**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.4)

> For HTTP/2 responses, a single `:status` pseudo-header field is
> defined that carries the HTTP status code field.
> This pseudo-header field MUST be included in all
> responses; otherwise, the response is malformed.
>
> HTTP/2 does not define a way to carry the version or reason phrase
> that is included in an HTTP/1.1 status line.

Comment: That's the core of my question. I found out that tornado actually does put personalized reason strings in some 4xx errors, so it's an accepted practice at least in tornado.

Comment: @StefanoBorini I've added some details about HTTP/2 that you may find interesting :)

Comment: So the reason phrase should not be used to return business logic errors?

Comment: @Konrad If they convey some meaning for the client, no. Use the response payload to return details on the errors. You may also want to check the [RFC 7807](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7807), as it defines some standards for reporting problems in HTTP APIs.

Comment: Hmm for me it always seemed reasonable to use this field to provide some meaningful information debug information e.g. 400 "Field foo contains invalid value" etc.

+ the following RFC https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html states:
"The individual values of the numeric status codes defined for HTTP/1.1, and an example set of corresponding Reason-Phrase's, are presented below. The reason phrases listed here are only recommendations -- they MAY be replaced by local equivalents without affecting the protocol."

Comment: @PawelGorczynski **The RFC 2616 is dead!** In the [words of Mark Nottingham](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2014/06/07/rfc2616_is_dead), _"**Don’t use RFC2616.** Delete it from your hard drives, bookmarks, and burn (or responsibly recycle) any copies that are printed out."_ If you are looking for the HTTP protocol reference, the RFCs you are looking for are 7130-7135. If you are looking for a standard to inform the client about errors in your HTTP API, then you should check the [RFC 7807](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7807). And **leave the reason phrase alone**.

Comment: @cassiomolin Thank you for the detailed clarification - I stand corrected ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you do, make sure it doesn't start with a number... some systems might validate the status code with regex and will include the first digit from the reason phrase with the actual response code and validation will fail, because it won't be a valid response code anymore.